# AlertDialog is not showing from another non-activity class

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an alert dialog from another class. I've looked up many Questions in StackOverflow but none worked.

I have two class `MainActivity.java` and `CustomInputDialog.java`. I am trying to show alert dialog from `CustomInputDialog.java` which is specified in `MainActivity.java`.

In my `MainActivity.java` I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<CustomInputDialog.Field> fields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                        new CustomInputDialog.Field(CustomInputDialog.Field.TYPE.TEXT, "Name", "", null),
                        new CustomInputDialog.Field(CustomInputDialog.Field.TYPE.DATE, "Start Date", "", null),
                        new CustomInputDialog.Field(CustomInputDialog.Field.TYPE.DATE, "End Date", "", null)
                ));

                ArrayList<String> result = CustomInputDialog.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Title", fields);
```

In my `CustomInputDialog.java` I have the following code:

```
final class CustomInputDialog {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomInputDialog";
    private static final String dateUISeparator = " : ";

    static ArrayList<String> showDialog(final Context context, String title, final ArrayList<Field> fields) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        final ArrayList<View> uis = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Field field : fields) {
            final View ui;
            switch (field.type) {
                 /**To long code it just creates specified views and saves it in `ui` variable*/
            }
            ui.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: ui added");
            layout.addView(ui);
            uis.add(ui);
        }
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setView(layout);

        final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: latch created");
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                /** Long code which updates `result` variable */
                dialog.dismiss();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                latch.countDown();
                Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: latch count down 2");
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show();
        Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: showing");
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: latch await");
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    static final class Field {
        private final TYPE type;
        private final String helpText;
        private final String initialValue;
        private final int choice;

        enum TYPE {
            TEXT, DATE, DOUBLE, INTEGER, CHOICE
        }

        Field(TYPE type, String helpText, String initialValue, @Nullable Integer choice) {
            this.type = type;
            this.helpText = helpText;
            this.initialValue = initialValue;
            if (choice == null) {
                this.choice = 0;
            } else {
                this.choice = choice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging it turns out that there are no exceptions thrown but still the variable : `alertDialog` in the method `showDialog` is not visible.

System Output:

```
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: ui created : editText
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: ui added
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: ui created : date
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: ui added
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: ui created : date
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: ui added
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: latch created
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: showing
D/CustomInputDialog: showDialog: latch await
```

Comment: which dialog are we talking about? I see you declare several with identical names in your code

Comment: @Stultuske The first dialog declared just after the method `showDialog`

Comment: what error generated?

Comment: There's way too much unnecessary information included here, if the only one doesn't work, please just include that and elaborate on what exactly didn't work.

Comment: @HardikTalaviya There is no error generated only the dialog is not appearing.

Comment: try to pass activity instead of context in dialog

Comment: @HardikTalaviya please elaborate what do you mean by passing Activity

Comment: please add debug point and check what is happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probleme seems to come from CountDownLatch which block the thread, you should instead make an interface in your custom dialog class where you have a `onResult()` (or whatever you want to call it) that you implement elsewhere.

You will have to pass a listener to your `showDialog()` that implements `onResult()` and in your OK button `onClick` you call `listener.onResult()`

The interface (in CustomInputDialog.java):

```
interface CustomInputDialogListener{
    void onResult(ArrayList<String> result);
}
```

The new parameters to pass to showDialog :

```
static void showDialog(final Context context, String title, final ArrayList<Field> fields, final CustomInputDialogListener listener) {
...
}
```

The end of your OK button onClick() :

```
dialog.dismiss();
listener.onResult(result);
//latch.countDown(); //you don't need that anymore
Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: latch count down 1");
```

You can remove the latch creation and try/catch block with the wait and return statements at the end

```
//Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: latch created");
//final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

/*try {
    Log.d(TAG, "showDialog: latch await");
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}*/
```

In your MainActivity.java you have 2 choices :

> Implementing CustomInputDialogListener and pass this to `showDialog`

The header of your MainActivity should look like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomInputDialog.CustomInputDialogListener {
    ...
}
```

And you will have to implement onResult() :

```
@Override
public void onResult(ArrayList<String> result) {
    this.result = result;
    doThings();
}
```

And when you call showDialog(), you pass this :

```
CustomInputDialog.showDialog(Test14dialog.this, "Title", fields, this);
```

> You directly implement the onResult :

```
CustomInputDialog.showDialog(Test14dialog.this, "Title", fields, new CustomInputDialog.CustomInputDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ArrayList<String> result) {
            this.result = result;
            doThings();
        }
    });
```

You shouldn't block threads when showing a dialog